# Derivative of vector and matrix product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus, jacobian

I was going through my linear algebra notes and got a bit confused with the following: let $x$ be a vector in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $A$ an $n\times n$ matrix, then
$$
\frac{\partial x'A}{\partial x}=A
$$
Since I was confused I tried the following "toy" example. Let $A$ be a $2\times 2$ matrix given by
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Thus
$$
x'A=\begin{bmatrix}a_{11}x_{1}+a_{21}x_{2}&a_{12}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now how do I take "the derivative" of each element? Is such thing the Jacobian of the function $f(x_{1},x_{2})=\left(a_{11}x_{1}+a_{21}x_{2},a_{12}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}\right)$?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why is $x^\textsf{T}A$ a $2 \times 1$ matrix? Now, if you take the derivative elementwise, how do you end up with a $2\times2$ matrix? None of this makes sense to me!

Comment: @azifmedrano I made a mistake in the question. Could you check the post again please?

Comment: The function $f(x) = x^T A$ is linear hence $Df(x_0) = f$. One can write $Df(x_0) (h) = h^T A$, this differs slightly from the usual premultiplication by $A$.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much, you mean $Df(x_{0})=A$ ?

Comment: @PedroIgnacioMartinezBruera No, I meant the function $f$. $Df(x_0)$ is a (linear) function.

Comment: @copper.hat sorry I did not understand. Could you explain me a little bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allright so I have checked the book "Matrix Algebra From a Statistician's Perspective" by Harville and I think I have reached an answer:

Let $\mathbf{f}=(f_{1},f_{2},\ldots,f_{n})'$ be a (column) vector function and $\mathbf{x}=\left(x_{1},x_{2},\ldots,x_{n}\right)'$. We define $\frac{d\mathbf{f}}{d\mathbf{x}'}$ as the Jacobian of such function, i.e. the $ij_{th}$ element is $\frac{df_{i}}{dx_{j}}$. In addition, we define $\frac{d\mathbf{f}'}{d\mathbf{x}}=\left(\frac{d\mathbf{f}}{d\mathbf{x}'}\right)'$ as the gradient matrix.

Thus, it is trivial to show that $\frac{d A\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}'}=A$ and therefore $\frac{d\mathbf{x}'A}{d\mathbf{x}}=\left(\frac{dA'\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}'}\right)'=\left(A'\right)'=A$.

In order to show that $\frac{dA\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}}=A'$ we know that $\frac{dA\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}}=\left(\frac{d\mathbf{x}'A'}{d\mathbf{x}'}\right)'$. The problem is that $\mathbf{x}'A$ is not a column of functions! What we need to do is to "redefine" it as the derivative of its transpose -$A\mathbf{x}$- in order to get a column (whose derivative we know how to compute). Since $\frac{dA\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}'}=A$ we conclude that $\frac{dA\mathbf{x}}{d\mathbf{x}}=A'$.