# Total Differentiation of $x^T A $ with respect to x

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

Total Differentiation of $ Ax $ with respect to $x$ is $A$. What is the total differentiation of $x^T A$ with respect to $x$ ?

I know that $ Ax $ is not entirely equal to $x^T A^T $ because of the change in the dimension of the output vectors from $(n,1)$ to $(1,n)$.

Hence my attempt to write it $x^T A$ as $A^T x$ and then its differential with respect to $x$, giving the result as $A^T$ is wrong?

Any help will be appreciated.

Edit 1:

Wolfram Alpha gives the following result,

[image]

I am not sure how to interpret this result.

Comment: Needs more detail. The derivative of a linear function (at any point) is itself. If you want to represent this by a matrix, you need to choose a basis. On $\mathbb{R}^n$ you can use the standard basis and on the dual space, $(\mathbb{R}^n)^*$ you can use the transpose/dual of this standard basis. So what is your understanding of a derivative of a function (e.g. between manifolds or between finite dimensional real vector spaces)?

Comment: Hi, I had the same doubt and ended up looking for the answer in a book. Here is my post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3808828/derivative-of-vector-and-matrix-product

Comment: Following the mathematicians convention instead of the machine learning one as you have in your post, the derivative isn't a matrix at all! The reason for this is because in the first example, we have the derivative of a column vector w.r.t. a column vector which gives a type (1,1) tensor. The second is the derivative of a row vector w.r.t. a column vector - a type (2,0) tensor. Matrices are only type (1,1) tensors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}$ be a $n \times m$ matrix. Define $f \colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$ by $f(x) = x^TA$. For $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ we have
\begin{align}
f(x + y) &= (x + y)^TA \\
&= (x^T + y^T)A \\
&= x^TA + y^TA \\
&= f(x) + y^TA.
\end{align}
Therefore the total derivative of $f$ at $x$, $Df(x)$, is the linear transformation given by
$$Df(x)y = y^TA.$$
If you wan't a matrix representation of $Df(x)$, you need a basis for $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^{1 \times m}$.